# Logsink to bigquery partitioning not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I created a logsink on folder level, so it neatly streams all the logs to Bigquery. In the logsink configuration, I specified the following options to let the logsink stream to (daily) partitions:

```
"bigqueryOptions": {
  "usePartitionedTables": true,
  "usesTimestampColumnPartitioning": true # output only
}
```

According to the [bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery#partition-tables) and [bigquery resource type](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.sinks), I would assume that this would automatically create partitions, but it doesn't. I verified that it didn't create the partitions with the following query:

```
#LegacySQL
SELECT table_id, partition_id from [dataset1.table1$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__];
```

Gives me:

```
[
  {
    "table_id": "table1",
    "partition_id": "__UNPARTITIONED__"
  }
]
```

Is there something I am missing here? It should have partitioned by date.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I did not wait long enough for the first partition to become active. Basically, a logsink streams data as unpartitioned. After a while, the data is partitioned by date, which is only visible after a few hours for the partition of today. Problem solved!

```
[
  {
    "table_id": "table1",
    "partition_id": "__UNPARTITIONED__"
  },
  {
    "table_id": "table1",
    "partition_id": "20200510"
  },
  {
    "table_id": "table1",
    "partition_id": "20200511"
  }
]
```